# How do i make a score counter for a dice in C# for Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make a scoreboard for a dice counter, for example if i roll a 1, you gain 1 point to the scoreboard, if you roll a 6, 6 points added to the scoreboard. Heres my code for the dice rolling:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dice : MonoBehaviour
{
// Array of dice sides sprites to load from Resources folder
private Sprite[] diceSides;

// Reference to this sprite renderer to change sprites
private SpriteRenderer rend;

// Use this for initialization
private void Start()
{
    // Assign Sprite Renderer component
    rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    // Load dice sides sprites to array from DiceSides subfolder of Resources folder
    diceSides = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/");
}

// If you left click over the dice then RollTheDice coroitine is started
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    StartCoroutine("RollTheDice");
}

//coroutine that rolls the dice
private IEnumerator RollTheDice()
{
    //variable to contain random dice side number
    //it needs to be assigned, let it be 0 initially
    int randomDiceSide = 0;

    //Final side or value that dice reads in the end of coroutine
    int finalSide = 0;

    //loop to switch dice sides randomly
    //before final side appears, 20 iterations here
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        // Pick up random value from 0 to 5 (all inclusive)
        randomDiceSide = Random.Range(0,5);

        //set sprite to upper face of dice from array according to random value
        rend.sprite = diceSides[randomDiceSide];

        // Pause before next iteration
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }

    // Assigning final side so you can use this value later in your game
    // for player movement for example
    finalSide = randomDiceSide + 1;

    // Show final dice value in console
    Debug.Log(finalSide);

    //Attempt to add to the score board in game
}
}
```

Also i have a code for a scoreboard, i just don't know how to link it with the "dice sides", here it is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int scoreValue = 0;
    Text score;

    void Start()
    {
        score = GetComponent<Text>(); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        score.text = "Score:" + scoreValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: i do not know, im new to this thing and idk what im doing

Comment: Oh, OK :) Well, UnityScript is a Javascript derivative created for Unity, but it's now deprecated in favour of C#.

Answer (score 0):

If I got all correctly the thing that you're asking for is that if you first roll the dice and it shows 1 and you roll the dice again and now the dice shows a 6. You want to add them together so the Scoreboard shows 7? If so that's the case you can add:

```
Scoreboard.scoreValue += finalSide;
```

at the bottom of your script like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dice : MonoBehaviour
{
// Array of dice sides sprites to load from Resources folder
private Sprite[] diceSides;

// Reference to this sprite renderer to change sprites
private SpriteRenderer rend;

// Use this for initialization
private void Start()
{
    // Assign Sprite Renderer component
    rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    // Load dice sides sprites to array from DiceSides subfolder of Resources folder
    diceSides = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/");
}

// If you left click over the dice then RollTheDice coroitine is started
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    StartCoroutine("RollTheDice");
}

//coroutine that rolls the dice
private IEnumerator RollTheDice()
{
    //variable to contain random dice side number
    //it needs to be assigned, let it be 0 initially
    int randomDiceSide = 0;

    //Final side or value that dice reads in the end of coroutine
    int finalSide = 0;

    //loop to switch dice sides randomly
    //before final side appears, 20 iterations here
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        // Pick up random value from 0 to 5 (all inclusive)
        randomDiceSide = Random.Range(0, 5);

        //set sprite to upper face of dice from array according to random value
        rend.sprite = diceSides[randomDiceSide];

        // Pause before next iteration
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }

    // Assigning final side so you can use this value later in your game
    // for player movement for example
    finalSide = randomDiceSide + 1;

    // Show final dice value in console
    Debug.Log(finalSide);
    Scoreboard.scoreValue += finalSide;
    //Attempt to add to the score board in game
   }
}
```